# Will pcap_set_filter() work with pcap_open_offline()?

Tags: c, filter, pcap, libpcap

I'm have written a `pcap` program that uses `pcap_open_live()` and progressively applies a filter (ie. recompiles the `pcap` filter and sets the filter again after an initial pcap_loop), and I would like to test it on some `pcap` files I have saved from `Wireshark`.

However, when I run the program, I can't even print out my packets unless I supply an empty filter to the `pcap_compile_filter`;

Is this just a feature of using `lpcap` on a saved file, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a snippet of the code for perusal:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char *dev = NULL;           /* capture device name */
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];      /* error buffer */
pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */
char filter_exp[] = "ip";           /* filter expression [3] */
struct bpf_program fp;          /* compiled filter program (expression) */
bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */
int num_packets = -1;           /* number of packets to capture  -1 => capture forever! */

printf("Filter expression: %s\n", filter_exp);

// open capture device
handle = pcap_open_offline("heartbeats2", errbuf);
if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pcap_open_offline failed: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device*/
if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* compile the filter expression */
if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, 0) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
        filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* apply the compiled filter */
if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
        filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

pcap_loop(handle, -1, gotPacket, NULL);

pcap_freecode(&fp);
pcap_close(handle);

printf("\nCapture complete.\n");

return(0);
}
```

The got packet function just prints out the payload of the packet;  The output is just:

```
Filter expression: ip

Capture complete.
```

Comment: @nos There's no vlan on the packets, I have the ethernet header size set to 14.  The protocol stack is ethernet, ip, udp for the packets I'm interested in.

Comment: Well, I tried it on Mountain Lion with a capture file I have, and with a `gotPacket` function that just prints "Got a packet".  If I `#if 0` out the `pcap_compile()` and `pcap_setfilter()` calls, it reports "Got a packet" for every packet in the file; if I remove the `#if 0` and `#endif`, it reports "Got a packet" for every IP packet in the file.  Note, however, that `"ip"` means IPv4, *NOT* IPv6 - you'd need `"ip6"` for IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your gotPacket function, it is not possible to say what is going on there.

As there are no other error messages, your program runs up to the end of the code and prints "Capture complete." message.

If your program works with pcap_open_live() and with empty filter, the only thing I would suspect that your pcap file may not contain any ip packet.

You can open your pcap file with wireshark and use "ip" filter in wireshark filter expression. If you can see some packet in wireshark, then your above program also should work with filter.

There are plenty of sites having BPF example. One example site could be http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html.